# How to check flink checkpoint is valid?

Tags: apache-flink, checkpoint

Is there a way to validate the checkpoint in flink? Sometimes the job ended successfully but when start it from checkpoint, it failed.

Comment: If nothing has changed (i.e., the job or the flink version), it shouldn't fail. How is it failing?

Comment: You can also use Flink State Processor API to try to verify the contents of the checkpoint, but as @DavidAnderson stated if nothing has changed it shouldn't fail, unless You are custom sources or other operators that have issues with state recovery.